# SQL Server round the decimal data if decimal part is 0

Tags: sql-server, decimal

In a SQL Server stored procedure I am casting a variable as decimal:

```
CAST( @ToValue as decimal(38,5) )
```

If the result is say 57282.0000 (decimal value is 0 ) I want it to appear as 57282.

Else I want to appear as 57282.48300 for example.

I cannot use float because if the value is greater than an 8 digit number, its displayed as exponential format.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Why not just format it in the presentation layer of your application?

Comment: Definitely do this in your application layer.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in the formatting options for your reporting software.

If for some reason that isn't possible then the following might work.

```
;WITH T(Val) AS
(
SELECT 57282 UNION ALL
SELECT 57282.48300
)
SELECT CASE WHEN 1= 0 THEN NULL  
            WHEN Val = FLOOR(Val) THEN CAST(CAST(Val AS INT)AS SQL_VARIANT) 
            ELSE CAST(Val AS DECIMAL(38,5))
            END
FROM T
```